# How to implement Search Bar behaviour like in iOS

Tags: android

I do not have any idea how to implement such search bar behaviour in Android, could you suggest something please?

Search bar should expand when user overscroll the page down and collapse when user scrolls up. Take a look at the video by link below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gwBiNISoFs

Comment: What behavior, scrolling up?

Comment: @m0skit0 Search bar should expand when user overscroll the page down

Comment: You can write your own customized search bar. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

i see the video you provide you can easily implement that behavior using motionLayout in android, i can't write the code for that here but here is the documentation:

MotionLayout:https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout

basically all u have to do is adding a swipe handler for your contact list and change the scale of searchView and title, android studio 4.2 provides easy interface to implement all that